# Find all contiguous subarrays of array in O(n) complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am stuck on finding a solution for finding all the contiguous subarrays of a given array in minimum time complexity O(n).

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Subarrays are:

```
[1][2][3][4][1,2][2,3][3,4][1,2,3][2,3,4][1,2,3,4]
```

I have done it with time complexity O(n^2) but for the large inputs taking lot of time and memory.

Are there any specific algorithms for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Since the output will contain *O(n²)* subarrays, there is no way to produce them in *O(n)* time.

Comment: Do you have the exact description of the problem? As mentionned by @trincot, it doesn't seem possible with the info you wrote.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin: counting takes O(1).

Comment: the statement says to find the number of subarrays from given array where the sum of those individual subarray results in perfect square root for ex:- in [1,2,3,4] there are 3 subarray whose sum are perfect square root i.e [1],[4],[2,3,4]

Comment: @MitchelPaulin: what difference does it make ?? Counting is still O(1).

Comment: @MitchelPaulin there are n(n+1)/2 subarrays. So to count them, all you need is an addition, a multiplication and a division.

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly n(n+1)/2 subarrays, which can be written as A[i..j] for all i and and all j≥i. The algorithm to generate all pairs is immediate (double loop) and cannot be improved.

If you just need to *output* the pairs (i, j), space O(1) suffices. If you need to *store* all pairs, O(n²). And if you need to store *all subarrays* in full, O(n³); in this case, the time also unavoidably grows to O(n³) and there is another nested loop.

---

**Update:**

This answer does not take int account the constraint "the sum of those individual subarray results in perfect square root" in the comments, which was added after the fact and cannot be considered part of the question.

Comment: If you need to store only 1 subarray[i, j] at a time for every i-j pair, O(n) space.